# Parameter passing in Systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

In the following Systemverilog code snippet:

```
xxx_model #    (.inst_name({inst_name,".ce_0"})) ce_0 (
...
..
);
```

I can't understand this part `inst_name({inst_name,".ce_0"})`.
Kindly help me understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code snippet:

1. xxx_model is a parameterized module that takes a parameter of type string named **inst_name**.
2. you are instantiating this module and **ce_0** is the name of the instance.
3. you are passing value **{inst_name,".ce_0"}** as the value of the parameter.

In this context Systemverilog will interpret curly braces as concatenation operator. **inst_name** in this line is probably a parameter being passed from the upper hierarchy. For the value for **inst_name**, kindly look for the instantiation of the enveloping module (the module one step upward in the module hierarchy).

Since **inst_name** is being used in a nested/recursive fashion here, the pattern in the code snippet seems to indicate that probably your code  would have **inst_name** as a parameter in all the modules in the hierarchy. And the purpose is to have a ***reflection*** of the hierarchical name of the instance available as a string parameter.

With this scheme of recursive parameter passing, if your module hierarchy is foo->bar->frop->zoo, the parameter **inst_name** inside the lower most instance in the hierarchy **zoo** would have a value **{inst_name, ".zoo"}**. Here **inst_name** being passed from above would recursively evaluate to "foo.bar.frop**, and as a result the value of **inst_name** in the instantiation would be **foo.bar.frop.zoo**.

Comment: Can I exactly declare like this inst_name = "foo.bar.frop";? Or inst_name = "foo.bar.frop**";

Comment: You do not want to do that. The very idea of using parameters is to make the code generic so that the same parameterized module can be used in some other hierarchy as well.